# Negative consequences of bumping `transaction_version` by more than one in a single release?

Tags: runtime, versioning

We bumped txver on a testnet when we didn't need to and then downgraded it, bumping txver again, so testnet is now 2 txvers ahead of `prod`.

We want to apply the runtime upgrade we have ready to both `prod` and this testnet without having to reset it or create two different runtime wasms (with a changed version for the testnet).
I believe we would thus have to increment `transaction_version` by 2 to get the upgrade to apply to both prod and testnet.

This would skip one `transaction_version` on prod. Is this a safe thing to do (considering metadata-sensitive services like indexers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally safe.

We usually use this to identify if the extrinsic is compatible. A higher version means a new extrinsic specification.

Just make sure you don't decrease that number.

---

More detail:

> https://docs.substrate.io/build/upgrade-the-runtime/
>
> The version of the interface for handling transactions. This parameter can be useful to synchronize firmware updates for hardware wallets or other signing devices to verify that runtime transactions are valid. The parameter allows hardware wallets to know which transactions they can safely sign. This number must be bumped if there is a change in the index of the pallets in the construct_runtime! macro or if there are any changes to dispatchable functions, such as the number of parameters or parameter types. If this number is updated, then the spec_version must also be updated.